# Neoclipse - How to connect to running Neo4j server using URL

Tags: neo4j, neoclipse

I am using neoclipse1.8 to connect to neo4j2.1.3 community server with below connection url
`http://localhost:7474/db/minicineasts` where minicineasts is the db folder read by neo4j server instance. below is the dialog i am getting

"----No connection to map to Object due to end of input:java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input-----"

The db is sample databse dowloaded from neo4j site and its perfectly working when i query through web admin.

What is the correct url to use, or is it a know issue with the versions of neoclipse and neo4j, any resolution appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: paste the specific java code, where you do the querying

Comment: i am not using java code to query. its java error thrown by neoclipse (developed in java) due to incorrect config.

Comment: the db-directory on disk is not reflected in the URL it is always `/db/data/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `http://localhost:7474/db/data` instead of the one I mentioned in the question and it worked. Please note "data" at the end.